# Ember refresh application.handlebars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have written a application using rails and emberjs. The application works but when I change content in the application.handlebars it does not reflect on the website after a refresh. All the other handlebars templates is updated immediately.

I have tried clearing the cache but the content don't change.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing some code. There is nothing special about application.handlebars so it should be refreshing like your other templates.

- Are you sure your application.handlebars template is being used? Could be it's not getting picked up at all and ember is just using the default.
- What steps are you taking to "refresh" the site? Are you the correct version of this template is being delivered to the browser?

Comment: Thank you @Mike. Seems that when I did a assets:precompile, Some version of the templates and application.js files where copied to my public folder.